# How to echo php within php?

Tags: php, forms, echo

How can I display the name the user entered back into the form if the user forgot to enter a password?
i.e. echo $submitted_user into value="" under Username.

```
if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $submitted_user = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
    echo '<form action="register.php" method="post">
    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>';

    exit();
}
```

Comment: Was an misinterpretation. Just replace `value=""` with `value="'.$submitted_user.'"`, since you're using single quotes in the echo statement. If you used echo with double quotes then `value="$submitted_user"` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the `$submitted_user` to value should do it.

```
if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $submitted_user = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
    echo '<form action="register.php" method="post">
    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="'.$submitted_user.'" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>';

    exit();
}
```

Comment: That didn't work.
I get "Notice: Undefined variable: submitted_user in C:\wamp\www\"

Comment: My bad, I misspelled the variable. It worked, thank you.